# Windows, Midnight Commander - как изменить редактор по умолчанию на Vim

Tags: windows, консоль, vim, редактор

В Линуксе было все просто, убираешь галочку в конфигурации и миднайт командер использует редактор, который в системе по умолчанию. У меня это был Vim. Я к нему привык, он клевый. Я его и в Windows установил в командную строку, но вот проблема - в винде это так не работает. Я убрал галочку, но теперь MC падает когда я пытаюсь открыть файл. Может кто-то знает как в Винде заставить Midnight Commander открывать файлы с помощью вима?

Comment: А где Вы взяли mc для винды? Или это так far назвали?

Comment: это именно MC, один в один
но только вот vim не могу прикрутить
через пакетный менеджер искал, но можно, наверно, и в гугле найти скачать
winget search midnight